# Induced map on cohomology by automorphisms of smooth hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Recently I am considering a strange question. Consider a complex smooth projective hypersurface $X\subset\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$, then an automorphism $f:X\rightarrow X$ induces an isomorphism on Betti cohomology
$$f^*:H^n(X,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^n(X,\mathbb{Z}),\quad f\mapsto f^*$$
Two different automorphisms $f_1,f_2$ induce the same action providing that they are homotopic to each other in complex manifold topology. In the case of complex rojective space $\mathbb{P}^n$, every automorphism can be represented by an invertible linear map $g:\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ which is homotopic to an invertiable diagonal linear map. So the map
$$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n)\rightarrow\text{Aut}(H^n(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathbb{Z}))$$
is not injective. For a hypersurface, the group $H^n(X,\mathbb{Z})$ can be pretty big. But two homotopic automorphisms of $X$ should also give the same action on $H^n(X,\mathbb{Z})$. Moreover, many hypersurfaces admit linear automorphisms. So could we say that in general (or for the most of the cases) the map
$$\text{Aut}(X)\rightarrow\text{Aut}(H^n(X,\mathbb{Z})),\quad f\mapsto f^*$$
is also not injective or not even injective after quotient $\{\pm\text{Id}\}$?